# last element with a class name in a div

Tags: jquery

how can i get the last div with class a in a div the id = test ?
in this case i have to get the div with content = 1000

```
<div id="test">
<div class="a">1</div>
..
..
<div class="a>1000</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use the [`:last` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/):

```
$('#test div.a:last')
```

Answer (score 16):

Without jQuery:

```
var divs = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("div");
var lastChild = divs[divs.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div#test div:last-child');
```

Comment: This works, but not "last" mentioned above by Tom!

Answer (score 1):

using the proposed [at](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

```
const nodesHighlighted = document.querySelectorAll('.day--highlight');
const lastNodeHighlighted = [...nodesHighlighted].at(-1);
```

at the current writing it's not supported by safari