# How to find the last child of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <div id="main">
  <div class="1"></div>
  <div class="2"></div>
  <div class="2"></div>
  <div class="3"></div>
  <div class="3"></div>
  <div class="4"></div>
 </div>
```

How we can write a selector using `:last-child` in jquery to find out the `last div with class 3` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [last element with a class name in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123228/last-element-with-a-class-name-in-a-div) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this selector... though your classes shouldn't be just numbers. They should start with a normal character.

`$("#main .3:last")`

FYI, `:last-child` checks if the target is last child of its parent. None of the elements with class `.3` are the last child of their parent.

Comment: -1 Direct child selector doesn't work an all current (microsoft) browsers.

Comment: @MihaiStancu care to show a jsfiddle of that? http://jsfiddle.net/eyvb6/1/ is working fine for me in ie7. There is also no direct child selector here.

Comment: @MihaiStancu I'm still curious about the direct child bug in IE, since jQuery does somewhat patch querySelectorAll in some areas. Can you demonstrate it?

Comment: Tested, couldn't replicate in a Windows VM, with up to date upgrades. Perhaps my recollections are from olden times (jQuery 1.2 -ish). Cant revert the downvote unless you edit your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.last()`:

```
$("#main .3").last();
```

http://api.jquery.com/last/

http://jsfiddle.net/E64Wm/1/

Answer (score 0):

`$('#main > .3').last()` should point to the right element

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
$('#main').find(':last-child');
```