# Is there any inbuild function in javascript to select last element with using class selector or element selector?

Tags: javascript, html, css

similar type of question is already asked [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123228/last-element-with-a-class-name-in-a-div/2123231).but my question is bit diffrent.

in my program frequently occur new element with using dom. here my question is

**is there any built in function in javascript that i can select last element frequently?**

here is an example

```
var para = document.createElement("div");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
```

given program append div element frequently and also i want to select div element frequently. similar with a class

thankyou in advance

Comment: You say javascript, but your example uses jquery, which one do you want to use? The answer to your javascript question is no.

Comment: sorry now take a look i thought that example in js should be long to explain?

Comment: So a javascript-only solution yes? Just to be clear. See answer below by @brk.

Comment: @wazz whats wrong with my answer?

Comment: Nothing. I just picked one. I have a question though. See your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no there is not any built in function in java script but u should try below logic and use it with jquery like `$(last_selector(".lastclass")).click(); for select last class` and `$(last_selector("div")).click(); for elect last element`

```js
function last_selector(select){
  if(select[0]=="."){
    var allSelect = document.getElementsByClassName(select.slice(1));
  }
  else{
    var allSelect = document.getElementsByTagName(select);
  }
  return allSelect[allSelect.length-1];
}

console.log(last_selector("div"))
console.log(last_selector(".last"))
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div class="last">last class</div>
<div>last element</div>
```

Comment: he is talking about only javascript??

Comment: already said you are right :p - removing comments now, as it's all good

Comment: What does `if(select[0]==".")` do?

Comment: for identify class

Comment: Oh, the first char, I see, tnx.

Comment: no problem :-) we all are here for exchanging our knowledge

Comment: What about `lastSelector('*')` or `lastSelector('[foo=bar]')` or `lastSelector(':hover')` or ...

Answer (score 2):

Use `querySelectorAll` and pass the class selector. Then target the last element and do whatever

```js
let getAllElem = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
getAllElem[getAllElem.length - 1].classList.add('green')
```

```css
.green {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
<div class="test">6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> It will give last span text inside every Div using $(elementName).children("span:last").text()

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log($('div').children("span:last").text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="time">2016</span><br>
  <span class="time">2017</span><br>
  <span class="time">2018</span><br>
  <span class="time">2019</span><br>
  <span class="time">2020</span><br>
  <span class="time">2021</span><br>
  <span class="time">2022</span><br>
  <span class="time">2023</span><br>
  <span class="time">2024</span> <br>
</div>
```